# When I sort data using hadoop, I get the error

Tags: java, hadoop

I want to use hadoop to compute the distance bewteen points and sort their result order by key, when run `hadoop jar knn.jar input output`, I get the errors as follows:

```
13/11/28 15:35:38 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_2013
10221205_0036_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
java.io.IOException: Type mismatch in key from map: expected or
g.apache.hadoop.io.Text, recieved org.apache.hadoop.io.DoubleWr
itable
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.col
lect(MapTask.java:1019)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewOutputCollector.
write(MapTask.java:690)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskInputOutputContext.w
rite(TaskInputOutputContext.java:80)
        at xautjzd.knn.hadoop.apache.KNN$KNNMapper.map(KNN.java
:35)
        at xautjzd.knn.hadoop.apache.KNN$KNNMapper.map(KNN.java
:1)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:1
45)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTas
k.java:764)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:36
4)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native M
ethod)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs
(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
```

My Code:

[image]

Comment: As the error says there is type mismatch. Can you show your driver class to see the data types you have set for map input? Basically depending upon the inputformat you have chosen the mapper will be given key. So confirm it or post your driver code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have set `conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class)` where as it should be `conf.setOutputKeyClass(DoubleWrtable.class)`